# How does unplugging battery and RAM (then reconnecting) fix Acer "black screen of death"?

Tags: laptop

How does unplugging battery and RAM fix Acer "black screen of death"?

Recently experienced issue where, when restarting my laptop (Acer Helios 300, 2018), I saw nothing but a black screen while the keyboard still lit up. Unplugging the power cable and doing a power reset (#1) helped temporarily, but on the next restart test, just showed the black screen again.
What ultimately helped was using the sources here:

- https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/comment/832619/#Comment_832619
- https://recoverit.wondershare.com/computer-problems/acer-laptop-black-screen.html (#8)
- https://forums.tomsguide.com/faq/how-to-fix-black-screen-in-acer-laptops.188316/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LBduIAF12M

which lead me to...

1. Turn off and unplug the laptop
2. Open up the underside
3. Unplug the battery
4. Remove the RAM sticks
5. Wait 15min
6. Reconnect everything back in (RAM + battery)
7. Plug laptop back in
8. Turn laptop back on successfully

What does this do exactly?
Why does this happen in the first place?
Is this something that happens to all Acers or just the Helios 300?

* Note that I rarely turn my computer off (and that this black screen issue has happened on the laptop 3 times since buying it)

Comment: I doubt reinserting the RAM did anything. But removing a laptop battery for 15 minutes, and putting it back in, is known to solve some problems (not just in that particular laptop or from that particular brand). The reason is the batteries are "smart" nowadays, they are not "normal AA batteries but bigger". They contain a controller. This laptop battery controller can sometimes be reset (e.g. by pressing a button or removing the battery for 15 minutes).

Comment: I think this question may be a duplicate. But I seriously doubt the accepted answer on that question.

Comment: @Gantendo The accepted answer in that linked question *does appear* to match the explanation in the youtube link in this post, but I am not a hardware person (and the video is of rather poor quality).

Comment: I hope some hardware specialist will comment on this post. I've heard both the "overcharged capacitor" theory and the "battery controllers suck" theory a couple of times. This is outside my area of expertise. When my hardware breaks I simply replace it.